# Quicktime Apple Script Error -

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I am getting the following error from a script that trims a .MOV, exports the new video and then closes the .MOV without saving. The script used to work just fine. (1 year ago?). The error is being triggered by Close document 1 saving no.

```
error "QuickTime Player got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

The code is:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"

activate

open alias "Ref Training:Bertrand - Angels vs Moose 1.MOV"

trim document 1 from 60 to 100

export document 1 in "/Volumes/Ref Training/Catalogue/In the Crease  Open A 1.mov" as POSIX file using settings preset "1080p"

close document 1 saving no 
end tell
```

The script works fine if I remove the "saving no" statement, except then I must intervene to tell quicktime to delete the file. I believe the UI may have changed for quicktime, as the input box on closing the file reads "Delete, Cancel, Save."

Any thoughts or advice? I am writing the script to manage ~650 trims.

Comment: Is "saving" still an option to "close" in Quicktime's Applescript dictionary?

Comment: Yes. The documentation still defines:close v : Close a document.
close specifier : the document(s) or window(s) to close.
[saving yes/‌no/‌ask] : Should changes be saved before closing?
[saving in file] : The file in which to save the document, if so.

Comment: I am able to run the code as written on an older computer. This suggests there has been a change to quickbooks/scripting that needs to be updated in the documentation.